A movie about immigrants
There is a father and a son who immigrated from Mexico. The father has his sister in US. Father and son live in poverty and son is not going to school often. Father works hard to raise the early teen son. However father gets a loan from his sister and then buys a cab and starts working from own. He identifies one of his old friends who he worked with during hard days and finds a work and go to it with him. This father's job is to cut and shape the top of a tree. He leaves the cab on the ground and he climbs the tree with the friend in the ground with the keys of the vehicle. This man steals the vehicle once the owner is in the top of the tree. This father gets into a world of troubles and tells his son what happened. They both cooperated and somehow found the cab which was sold by the thief to a used vehicles showroom. The father and the son steal it from there, but the police got them arrested. Finally they were evaluated by many government officials and the child was sent to his aunt while the father had to leave the US.

I think you are looking for A Better Life
All the plot elements are there except it was a work truck and no cab:

Carlos Galindo (Demián Bichir) works as a gardener with Blasco Martinez (Joaquín Cosio) in Los Angeles
Carlos asks his sister Anita (Dolores Heredia) for a loan to purchase Blasco's truck and tools.
On the first day, Santiago steals the truck
They discover that Santiago has sold the truck and sent the money to his family back home to El Salvador. 
They find the garage where Santiago sold the truck and steal it back. However, on their way home, they are pulled over by the police, and Carlos is arrested and incarcerated as an illegal immigrant.


You are right, thank you! I am from Sri Lanka, I think it's regional use of the word, 'work' cab and the work truck.
